# How to update SWF without re-compiling the FLA

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

All my SWF files run the same script class, There are a lot of `.swf` files to be updated after making some changes in that script class, Normally to see changes in SWF files I would open the FLA files and compile. Since there are thousands of SWF it will take too much effort.

**is there any way to update all existing `.swf` files without a need to re-compile `.fla` files**

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess by "refresh" what you actually mean is recompile.

To automate that, you have a two options:

1- JSFL, which is a pain in the ass.

2- Write a program that will compile every .fla throught command line, which somehow can be even more painful

I'm not an expert in both of the solutions so let me just give you a guide on how to do it the first way: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2004/08/jsfl_fla_batch.html

Comment: Thank you alot, you are a time saver

Answer (score 0):

By definition, it's impossible to create or modify a (million of) swf (pdf, doc, gif, php...) file without opening it.

Comment: But fla files dont contain any code only have script name when ı import the swf file, the swf runs changed script but as it was before changes. I mean ı need some thing that would refresh swf.

Comment: @MetinIlhan So what do you mean by "refresh"?

Comment: ı want my swf updated, for example, when swf executed it shows "1", then I modify the class file to make swf shows "2" still when ı executed swf it shows "1", to update swf ı will have to open fla file and execute it, ı want my swf to be updated without reexecuting the fla file, thanks

Comment: @MetinIlhan `ı want my swf to be updated without reexecuting the fla file`... What do you exactly mean by `updated`?

Comment: my swf show "1", it must show "2" after ı modify the class, by mean  reexecuting ı mean re publish fla to get updated swf

Comment: It's difficult to understand you but the basic answer is no you can't refresh a swf without republishing it. You can automatize the process using JSFL.

Comment: Apart from going through the SWF's bytes themselves to find and change that specific variable from a "1" to a "2". Is numbers all you want to change? Consider this tool **[AS3SWF](https://github.com/claus/as3swf/wiki)** to modify/create SWFs using code (Google its name for more info/help) or also consider **[this article](http://bmanatee.blogspot.com/2013/08/basic-swf-bytecode-modification-avm2as3.html)** on whats inside an SWF file.